# How can I run two react native applications?

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to run my react native app twice: my device + simulator.

I don't mind using two metro bundler instances.  How can I do that?

Right now, both my devices connect to 8081 - and whenever one connects, it kicks the other one off.

(I first built from XCode to my device/simulator, and then I run `react-native start`)

Comment: Why you want to do so?

Comment: @KetanParmar, in my case, I wanted to test the push notification sending across multiple devices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`react-native run-ios` command supports a `port` parameter after [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/33d710e8c58ef1dc69816a59ac1cf390894e7cb9). You can try to use this parameter to run your app in two different ports with two different builds.

***From commit notes:***

> adds `--port` option to `react-native run-ios` as well as patches port …
>
> **Summary:** The pull request adds the `--port` option to `run-ios`
>   allowing a developer to build and launch a react-native app using a
>   single command line like this: `react-native run-ios --port 8088`
>
> It defaults to the current port 8081.

Comment: In the interest of completeness for the sake for future readers, the `--port` parameter is supported for `react-native run-android`, `react-native run-ios`, and `react-native start`. So one can have different apps running on the same device or multiple devices with the `deviceID` parameter.

Answer (score 15):

1. Install the App for the first time on your real ios device using `npx react-native run-ios --device "Kasra’s iPhone"`, of course replace `Kasra’s iPhone` with the name of your real ios device.
2. run `npx react-native start --port 8082`
3. Open the app on ios real device and hit `Ctrl + D` to open the dev menu, or shake the device to open it.
4. Select the `Configure Bundler` option
5. For the IP, **DO NOT USE** 127.0.0.1, use the IP of your system, execute `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` in terminal to find your IP based on your OS.
6. For the port number use `8082`
7. select `Apply Changes`, it should automatically start the app on your ios real device
8. Now open another terminal window
9. `npx react-native run-ios` to run it on your simulator.

Now you have two bundlers running side by side on ports 8081 and 8082 simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

tldr; You need to run metro on a different server and then open the simulator device on that server, then from dev tools and change the port&host

For this answer I am assuming one of your React Native Application is running fine on default server. Steps to run another application -

**Step 1**: run metro-bundler server with specified port

```
npx react-native start --port=8088
```

**Step 2**: run the device on same server

```
iOS: npx react-native run-ios --port=8088 --simulator="iPhone 13"

Android: npx react-native run-android --port=8088
```

(writing the same without equal sign also works)

npx react-native run-ios --port 8088 --simulator "iPhone 13"

**Step 3**: Change the host server and port number in dev tools after launching the app

iOS: Command + D (or ctrl+cmd+Z) in Mac and Ctrl + D in windows
Click on Configure Bundler option
provide host as localhost (or 127.0.0.1) and port as 8088 then click apply changes

Android: Command + M in Mac and Ctrl + M in windows
Click on Change Bundle Location
change it to localhost:8088 then press ok

**Note1-if you are running your app on your phone then provide its address as mentioned in Kasra's answer above**

**NOTE2- Sometimes what I experienced was that shake keypress(cmd+d or ctrl+cmd+z) which you need to access the configure bundler option on iOS was stuck, it simply didn't respond whatever shortcut I tried, even opening it from menubar didn't work,
in that case, close the app and open again using command from step2, and now open the terminal window in which metro is running, there will be two options press d and press r, if the active window is terminal window then shake option will work after pressing d , attaching my VScode terminal screenshot for reference, you may have metro running in any terminal
this thing took a 2 hours for me, hence I thought it's worth mentioning**

[image: vscode screenshot of Note2]

Answer (score 0):

Everything is much eseaier,

1. Run you Emulator and connect your device to computer
2. Run `adb devices` in terminal. It will show your device ids

```
List of devices attached
RKCB91214AA device
emulator-1258   device
```

3. Run `npx react-native run-android --deviceId="RKCB91214AA" --port=8082` and `npx react-native run-android --deviceId="emulator-1258" --port=8081` for each device on different terminals. Just make sure that commands have different ports.
4. Open `React Native DevMenu` (by shaking phone) on `RKCB91214AA` device and change `Bundle Location` to `localhost:8082`